# How to custom order two different sections in a tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have successfully implemented two different sections in my table view. Section 1 has 3 cells displayed first, then section 2 has 12 displayed afterwards.

I would like to have it ordered so section 1 has its 3 cells mixed into section 2 (12 cells) So in this case it would be displayed every 4 cells. I would like to code it in a way that when the section 2 cells increases over time it keeps section 1 every 4 cells.

Here is the tableview delegate functions I have at the moment

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.

    return 2
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (section == 0) {
    return 3 // At the moment I have hard coded it will change it to array.count
    } else {
        return eventNameArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MovingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WhatsOnMovingTableViewCell
     // Do something!
    return cell
    }
    else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WhatsOnTableViewCell
    // Do something!
    return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Mixing the cells of the sections will remove the need / capability of different sections - you will just have one section and do the logic in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` a little bit different. I dont understand what exactly you are asking for

Comment: I have two different reusable cells I have configured as you can see in cellForRowAtIndexPath. At the moment the table view displays like this Moving cell | Moving cell|Moving Cell | Cell|Cell|Cell|Cell|Cell etc. But I would like to reorder it so the moving cells are mixed in-between the cells like this Cell|Cell|Cell|Cell|MovingCell|Cell|Cell|Cell|Cell|Moving Cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix the cells of different sections.
Since that is what you want the solution is to remove the sections all together or include more sections:

- Solution 1:
  1 Section with x cells: `Cell|Cell|Cell|Cell|MovingCell|Cell|Cell|Cell|Cell|Moving Cell`
- Solution 2: y Sections with 1 or z cells - `Cell|Cell|Cell|Cell` + `MovingCell` + `Cell|Cell|Cell|Cell` + `Moving Cell`

I will show you the code that would be needed for Solution 1. You will need to have some variable indicating what the length of `Cell`-semi-sections would be, e.g. `let cellCountBeforeMoving = 4`:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3 + eventNameArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.item + 1) % (cellCountBeforeMoving + 1) == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MovingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WhatsOnMovingTableViewCell
         // Do something!
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WhatsOnTableViewCell
        // Do something!
        return cell
    }
}
```

Note the indexes are now a little offset and you have to be careful accessing the array. The probably correct way to get the element corresponding to a given indexPath is

```
eventNameArray[indexPath.item - ((indexPath.item + 1) / (cellCountBeforeMoving + 1))]
```

Solution 1 will end up something like: (you need some var which gives you the number of interplaced MovingCells)

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return movingCells * 2
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section % 2 == 1 {
        return 1
    }
    return cellCountBeforeMoving
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section % 2 == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MovingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WhatsOnMovingTableViewCell
         // Do something!
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WhatsOnTableViewCell
        // Do something!
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I tried out solution 1 as it makes more sense to me. I seem to be getting the error fatal error: Array index out of range. It is crashing when in cellForRowAtIndex setting up "`Cell" any ideas? Im guessing this is because it is thinking "Cell" has more rows than the data it actually has

Comment: @user4671001 you have to be careful accessing the index, since indexPath.item no longer is the correct index in the `eventNameArray`. The correct index probably is `indexPath.item - ((indexPath.item + 1) / (cellCountBeforeMoving + 1))` or something along those lines

Comment: I can get rid of the crash by only returning the eventNameArray.count, but then this will remove 3 of the event cells for the tableview. Like I said it seems like "Cell" thinks it has the extra 3 cells so it searches inside its Arrays to populate them and crashes since there is no more data

Comment: Just saw your other comment, so how would you suggest fixing this I'm not too sure what you mean. Thanks luk, I have moved forward a lot quicker than I thought!!!

Comment: yes, that is what I said, when getting the item from the `eventNameArray` you have you subtract the amount of already existing `MovingCell`s before the current cell

Comment: I mean that instead of writing something like `eventNameArray[indexPath.item]` you have to write `eventNameArray[indexPath.item - ((indexPath.item + 1) / (cellCountBeforeMoving + 1))]`

Comment: @user4671001 you are welcome - I am however not 100% sure that the calculation I wrote above is correct in every situation. Might cause problems in some corner cases. You might and probably should go over the math once again by yourself to fully understand what the statements mean - to be able to fix them in case a problem occurs. And feel free to upvote my answer in addition to accepting it :)

Comment: How would I access an index path of an array inside the "Moving Cell" cellForRowAtIndexPath. It crashed with index out of array with both movingImagesArray[indexPath.item] and the other example you gave me which works with eventNameArray inside of the "Cell"

Comment: `((indexPath.item + 1) / (cellCountBeforeMoving + 1)) - 1` !?